# PHP: Submitting form data via $_POST works for all fields except radio buttons

Tags: php, forms, post, radio-button

I am new to PHP and hope someone can help me with this.

I have an HTML form with a number of inputs and textareas. On Submit I pass the form to another PHP page that generates an email with its values.

For text inputs and textareas everything works as intended but for the radio buttons I can't get it to show me the value on the targetted page.

The radio buttons look as follows and the classes used there are only to apply some CSS. 
There is only one form on the submitting page, all radios have the same name ("`requestType`") and there are no other elements using this name.
Also, I added a quick JavaScript snippet for testing to alert their value on change and this worked as well, so the issue seems to be only with the `$_POST`.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here or what alternatives I could try here ?

My HTML (on the submitting page):

```
<input type="radio" class="customRadio radioDefault" id="requestType1" name="requestType" value="Value1" />
    <label for="requestType1">Value1</label>
<input type="radio" class="customRadio triggerDiv" id="requestType2" name="requestType" value="Value2" />
    <label for="requestType2">Value2</label>
```

My PHP (on the targetted page):

```
$_POST["requestType"]
```

**Update:**
As per RiggsFolly I tried to check whether it recognises that a radio button is checked which it seems it does, it just doesn't return anything as the following just returns "xx":

```
if(isset($_POST['requestType'])){
    $theSelectedOne = $_POST['requestType'];
    echo "radio value: x" . $theSelectedOne . "x";
}else{
    echo "boohoo";
}
```

Comment: And that's all is packed into the form, I guess?

Comment: Try this: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php4p10.html

Comment: `isset($_POST['requestType']) ? $_POST['requestType'] : 'not set DEFAULT value';`

Comment: @nicael: Yes, radio buttons and all the other fields are within the same form.

Comment: you may need to show us more code and how/where that's being used. it may also be JS related.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Thanks for this - I'll have a look.

Comment: @Fred-ii- WoHoo I got me a spell checker on SO at last. LOL

Comment: @RiggsFolly hehe, that you do ;-) *added my 2 cents* cheers

Comment: @Fred-ii- Always welcome my friend

Comment: as I said earlier in comments; you need (not may at this point) to show us your complete JS related to the JS and the PHP. this is getting to be guesswork. If you have form tags and other inputs, modify your question. There's nothing we can do without it.

Comment: @Fred-ii-This got resolved with the help of RiggsFolly - see comments below. Thanks for your help !

Comment: a ternary operator does the same thing just in one go, but Riggs' answer works. welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Radio buttons (and Checkboxes) are only passed back to the form in either the $_POST or $_GET arrays if they are actually checked. I notice you do not auto check one of them as you create the HTML so nothing is likely to be returned if the user makes no selection.

So the best way to test if they were checked or not is to test for the existance of their name in the $_POST array

```
if ( isset( $_POST['requestType'] ) ) {
    // a selection was made
    // so now test the value to see which one was checked
    $theSelectedOne = $_POST['requestType'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I will check this out. The form is generated dynamically and I use JS to check all radio buttons with the class "radioDefault" using the following on page load: find('input[type=radio].radioDefault').prop('checked', true);

Comment: Update: This is weird. So I tried your approach and also added an alert in case the iff statement is not true but it does say it's true just doesn't return anything - I will add the test code to the post above.

Comment: I found the issue - the JS was overwriting the value. So this is resolved. However, your suggestion pushed me in the right direction. Sorry for that and thanks for your help, it definitely was one ! :)

Comment: @keewee279 great, but having posted your JS right off the bat, would have resolved it faster; *just saying* ;-) and I had a feeling that's what the issue was, or played a major role, as [I stated in this comment...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30939746/php-submitting-form-data-via-post-works-for-all-fields-except-radio-buttons?noredirect=1#comment49914478_30939746) 7 mins.after your original post.